# Php code outputting file, but not sending confirmation email

Tags: php, html

There is a form on the site I am working on, the user data is put in a csv file, and stored on our server; followed by an email notifying me there is a new file on the server with the csv file attached.

However recently the form stopped sending the confirmation email, although it still creates the file on the server.

this is the code:

```
          <?php
$fileDir = "csv/";
?>
           <?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
?>
           <?php
    $filename = date("ymd_His", time()) . ".csv";
    $myFile   = $fileDir . $filename;
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "TYPE,NAME,NUMBER,SIZE,BACKSTAMP,DESCRIPTION\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    if ($_POST['qty_Royal_Doulton_Figurines'] > 0) {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $_POST['qty_Royal_Doulton_Figurines']; $counter += 1) {
            $stringData = "Royal Doulton Figurine," . $_POST['name_Royal_Doulton_Figurines_' . $counter] . "," . $_POST['number_Royal_Doulton_Figurines_' . $counter] . "\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        }
    }
    if ($_POST['qty_Royal_Doulton_Jugs'] > 0) {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $_POST['qty_Royal_Doulton_Jugs']; $counter += 1) {
            $stringData = "Royal Doulton Jugs," . $_POST['name_Royal_Doulton_Jugs_' . $counter] . "," . $_POST['number_Royal_Doulton_Jugs_' . $counter] . "," . $_POST['size_Royal_Doulton_Jugs_' . $counter] . "\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        }
    }
    if ($_POST['qty_Royal_Doulton_Bunnykins'] > 0) {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $_POST['qty_Royal_Doulton_Bunnykins']; $counter += 1) {
            $stringData = "Royal Doulton Bunnykins," . $_POST['name_Royal_Doulton_Bunnykins_' . $counter] . "," . $_POST['number_Royal_Doulton_Bunnykins_' . $counter] . "\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        }
    }
    if ($_POST['qty_Royal_Doulton_Beatrix_Potter'] > 0) {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $_POST['qty_Royal_Doulton_Beatrix_Potter']; $counter += 1) {
            $stringData = "Royal Doulton Beatrix Potter," . $_POST['name_Royal_Doulton_Beatrix_Potter_' . $counter] . "," . $_POST['number_Royal_Doulton_Beatrix_Potter_' . $counter] . ",," . $_POST['backstamp_Royal_Doulton_Beatrix_Potter_' . $counter] . "\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        }
    }
    if ($_POST['qty_Other_Royal_Doulton_Pieces'] > 0) {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $_POST['qty_Other_Royal_Doulton_Pieces']; $counter += 1) {
            $stringData = "Other Royal Doulton Pieces," . $_POST['name_Other_Royal_Doulton_Pieces_' . $counter] . "," . $_POST['number_Other_Royal_Doulton_Pieces_' . $counter] . ",,," . $_POST['desc_Other_Royal_Doulton_Pieces_' . $counter] . "\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
?>
           <?php
}
?>

            <?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to          = 'sales@seawaychina.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject     = 'COLLECTION FOR SALE';
//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$message     = $_POST['First_Name'] . $_POST['Last_Name'] . "\n" . $_POST['Address1'] . $_POST['Address2'] . "\n" . $_POST['City'] . ", " . $_POST['State'] . " " . $_POST['Zip'] . "\n" . $_POST['Country'] . "\n" . "Phone: " . $_POST['Phone'] . "\n" . "Fax:  " . $_POST['Fax'] . "\n" . $_POST['Email'] . "\n--------------------\n" . $_POST['Comments'];
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers     = "From: " . $_POST['Email'] . "\r\nReply-To: " . $_POST['Email'];
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-" . $random_hash . "\"";
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/csv/" . $filename)));
//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>
           --PHP-mixed-<?php
echo $random_hash;
?> 
            Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php
echo $random_hash;
?>"

            --PHP-alt-<?php
echo $random_hash;
?> 
            Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

            COLLECTION FOR SALE

            --PHP-alt-<?php
echo $random_hash;
?> 
            Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

            <font face="arial">
            <strong><?php
echo $_POST['First_Name'];
?> <?php
echo $_POST['Last_Name'];
?></strong><br />
            <?php
echo $_POST['Address1'];
?> <?php
echo $_POST['Address2'];
?><br />
            <?php
echo $_POST['City'];
?>, <?php
echo $_POST['State'];
?> <?php
echo $_POST['Zip'];
?><br />
            <?php
echo $_POST['Country'];
?><br />
            Phone: <?php
echo $_POST['Phone'];
?><br />
            Fax: <?php
echo $_POST['Fax'];
?><br />
            <?php
echo $_POST['Email'];
?><br /><br />
            <?php
echo $_POST['Comments'];
?>
           </font>

            --PHP-alt-<?php
echo $random_hash;
?>--

            --PHP-mixed-<?php
echo $random_hash;
?> 
            Content-Type: text/csv; name="<?php
echo $filename;
?>" 
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
            Content-Disposition: attachment 

            <?php
echo $attachment;
?>
           --PHP-mixed-<?php
echo $random_hash;
?>--

            <?php
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message   = ob_get_clean();
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?> 


            <style type="text/css">
            <!--
            body,td {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #333333;
            font-size: 12px;
            }
            input,select,textarea {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #333333;
            }
            -->
            </style>
            <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3;URL=http://www.seawaychina.com" />
            <br> 
            <table width="500" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
            <td align="center"><img src="images/header.gif" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center"><p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Thank you, your list has been submitted!</p>
              <p><font color="#FF0000"><i>Please note that it may take up to a month for us to process your list. Thank you for your patience!</i></font> <br />
                </p>
              <p><br />
              </p></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

and below is a link to the form:

http://www.seawaychina.com/sellerform.aspx

could you please help me out?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow - you'll find you get more responses to a question like this if you show you've tried to help yourself. No-one wants to read a huge script, most of which is irrelevant. What I'd suggest is writing a very simple test script which just calls mail(). If that doesn't work, then you know it's not your logic, it's the underlying system, and you can then turn to your server logs etc.

Answer (score 4):

Do you get `mail sent`? If so, that just means the email's been handed over to the SMTP server, it does **NOT** mean it was actually delivered to the recipient's mailbox. If you do get mail sent, then check your mail server's logs to see what happened to the email after php handed it over.

If you get mailfailed, then something's wrong with your PHP configuration (bad smtp server settings?), or the email was so mangled that it was rejected outright by your smtp server.